# Other users unable to access shared Directory

Tags: permissions, users, shared-folders

I created a directory in /home and changed its group from *root* to *sharing*. Other users in the group *sharing* are unable to access the directory. I have tried a lot of ways to solve this problem but I am completely stuck now. These are the steps I followed in creating the group and directory.

```
john@hp:~$ sudo groupadd sharing
john@hp:~$ sudo adduser john sharing
Adding user `john' to group `sharing' ...
Adding user john to group sharing
Done.
john@hp:~$ sudo adduser sally sharing
Adding user `sally' to group `sharing' ...
Adding user sally to group sharing
Done.
john@hp:~$ cd ..
john@hp:/home$ sudo mkdir sharedMusic
john@hp:/home$ sudo chgrp sharing sharedMusic/
john@hp:/home$ ls -ld sharedMusic/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root sharing 4096 Nov 22 16:19 sharedMusic/
john@hp:/home$ sudo chmod 2770 sharedMusic/
john@hp:/home$ ls -ld sharedMusic/
drwxrws--- 2 root sharing 4096 Nov 22 16:19 sharedMusic/
john@hp:/home$ cd sharedMusic/
john@hp:/home/sharedMusic$
```

Although I am able to enter the directory, the other user *sally* who is a member of the group *sharing* is getting this message.

```
sally@hp:~$ cd ..
sally@hp:/home$ ls -l
total 28
drwx------  2 root    root    16384 Oct 28 13:52 lost+found
drwxrws---  2 root    sharing  4096 Nov 22 16:19 sharedMusic
drwxrw-r-- 23 john    john     4096 Nov 22 11:22 john
drwxrwx--- 15 sally   sally    4096 Nov 22 12:12 sally
sally@hp:/home$ cd sharedMusic/
bash: cd: sharedMusic/: Permission denied
```

I am the default user with root privileges whereas *sally* is a regular user with no *sudo* privilege but she is in the group *sharing* and hence should have got access in the shared directory. I have given zero permissions to world since I don't want anyone else to have any access to the directory other than the group and root. Help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem is finally solved. I just refreshed the terminal and now the users are getting access. Actually I had login into the terminal session of *sally* and was trying to access the shared directory. I closed the all the terminals, switched to sally's account, and then opened the terminal and got access to it.